# Converting an image of unknown format to a particular format

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am using WPF to try to convert an image, which is in an unknown format, into an image that must be in the 8 bits per pixel gray scale format.  In addition, I have to extract a byte array containing the pixel data and pass that on to other software for processing.

The images are passed to my code as an object that contains a `byte` array which contains all of the bytes of the image.  That is, if the image is a jpeg, the bytes that make up that jpeg image on file are in a `byte` array property of the object.

Here's what I've written so far:

```
byte[] imageBytes;
try {
    BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
    try {
        using ( MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream( snapshot.ImageData ) ) {
            src.BeginInit();
            src.CacheOption  = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            src.StreamSource = memoryStream;
            src.EndInit();
        }
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        . . . 
        return;
    }
    FormatConvertedBitmap dst = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
    dst.BeginInit();
    dst.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Gray8;
    dst.Source = src;
    dst.EndInit();

    // Compute the dst Bitmap's stride (the length of one row of pixels in bytes).
    int stride = ( ( dst.PixelWidth * dst.Format.BitsPerPixel + 31 ) / 32 ) * 4;

    // Put the pixel bytes into the imageBytes array.
    imageBytes = new byte[ stride * dst.PixelHeight ];
    dst.CopyPixels( Int32Rect.Empty, imageBytes, stride, 0 );
} catch ( Exception ex ) {
    . . .
    return;
}
```

The code runs, but when I pass the pixel bytes retrieved by the call to `CopyPixels` on to the other software, the image is not being processed properly.

I have added code which outputs the `FormatConvertedBitmap` to a .BMP file.  I've also added code which outputs the `byte` array returned by `CopyPixels` to a .RAW file.  When I compare the byte streams in a hex file editor, taking into account that the formats are different & the image bytes in the BMP are after the header & color table, the bytes don't match up, especially at the beginning.  That is, for one image, the first 4 bytes in the BMP are 00 00 00 00, but the first 4 bytes in the RAW file are 00 23 40 00.

I would have thought that the byte array returned by `CopyPixels` would be identical to the bytes from the BMP, from the first to the last.

So my question is, are my assumptions wrong?  If they are wrong, how do I get what I'm looking for?  And if they're right, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of the raw pixel data you should perhaps encode the FormatConvertedBitmap (by e.g. a BmpBitmapEncoder) and return the encoded buffer.

Comment: @Clemens:  The software I have to feed the pixel data to requires raw pixel data.

Comment: Ok, your stride calculation is wrong. For an 8-bit image the stride is identical to the bitmap width.

Comment: I found the problem.  It wasn't in the code I've posted.  It was in the configuration of the software that I send the image on to.